# How to Display Hierarchial data in MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to display hierarchial data in my view - I have 2 models (parent/child linked)

Models:

```
public class Clinic
{
    public int ClinicId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Clinic Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

}

public class Property
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    public int ClinicId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Property Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
 }

public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }

}
```

My controller is builds this Linq query - which displays fine in LinqPad:

```
    //
    // GET: /Property/Overview/
    public ActionResult Overview()
    {
   // original code - replaced following help below
   //  var ovw =
   //         (from c in db.Clinics
   //          select new
   //          {
   //              c.Name,
   //              Properties =
   //                  from p in db.Properties
   //                  where p.ClinicId == c.ClinicId
   //                  select new
   //                  {
   //                      p.Address
   //                  }
   //                  });

        IEnumerable<Clinic> ovw = from c in db.Clinics
        select c;

        return View(ovw);
    }
```

My view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<ttp.Models.Clinic>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Overview";
}

<h2>Overview</h2>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 @item.Name
        <br />
 if (item.Properties != null){
    foreach (var item2 in item.Properties) {
        @item2.Address <br />

 if (item2.Rooms != null){
    foreach (var item3 in item2.Rooms) {
        @item3.RoomName <br />
     }

     }
    }
   }
```

It should display:

```
Clinic1
   Property1
      Room1
      Room2
      Room3

   Property2
      Room4
      Room5

Clinic2
   Property3
      Room6
....
```

But instead just shows:

```
Clinic1
Clinic2
Clinic3
```

This will only ever populate the first level of data of Clinics - not the child Properties, or the child Rooms of Properties.

Can anyone please help me fix my controller or my view?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've plus 1'd the answers above, as they are very helpful - but the actual problem/answer was in my model definitions - to access the linked tables in the controller/view, I had to add VIRTUAL to the linked property:

Where I had:

```
public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

That should have been:

```
public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
```

I hope this helps someone else with this problem.

Thanks to Steve and Ufuk for your help, and time.

Mark

Answer (score 4):

You should create instances of Clinic and Property classes. You are using anonymous types.

Also don't forget to call ToList() for Properties because your query will return `IEnumerable<Property>` or `IQueryable<Property>`.

```
IEnumerable<Clinic> ovw = from c in db.Clinics
                          select new Clinic
                          {
                            Name = c.Name,
                            Properties =(from p in db.Properties
                                         where p.ClinicId == c.ClinicId
                                         select new Property
                                         {
                                             Address = p.Address
                                         }).ToList()
                          });
```

Comment: Hi - thank you - I tried the query above, but was greeted with the error: -  The entity or complex type 'ttp.Models.Clinic' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."} System.SystemException {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: @fixit Then you should just select c variable in your query. EF should fill the values itself. However you have to make sure Properties is mapped correctly.

Comment: Hi - VS now advises: the type or namespace 'Select' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: from c in db.Clinics select c; 
Is this how you wrote it?

Comment: Hi - the query, rewritten from your post above, now looks like: IEnumerable<Clinic> ovw = from c in db.Clinics
                    select new Clinic
                    {
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Properties = (from p in db.Properties
                    where p.ClinicId == c.ClinicId
                    select new Property
                    {
                    Address = p.Address
                    }).ToList()
                    }
            from c in db.Clinics
            select c
            );

Comment: Since you are using EF you don't have to new up Clinic objects. It should already fill and return them. Try the query in the comment above and see what you get.

Comment: Hi - I've updated my original post, to reflect the query you've helped with/suggested. It now returns just a list of top level clinics - not properties or rooms.  If EF should populate these automatically, are my models wrong?  Thank you again.

Comment: @fixit It seems like there is something wrong with your EF mappings also.  I think you should ask another question about that.

Comment: Hi - it was my models - I wasn't using VIRTUAL on the links... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually returning a list of Clinics because you've used

```
select new { ... }
```

Instead you want to just get the clinics. The model and collection already exists. There's no need to recreate it:

```
var ovw = db.Clinics;
```

If you're trying to have a view model which is separate from the db model (which is good practice) look into AutoMapper or manually map from the db Clinic to a view model Clinic. Then instead of select new { ... } you would use

```
select new vmClinic { Name = c.Name, ... }
```

where vmClinic is your viewmodel clinic.

Comment: Sorry, posted mine the same time as Ufuk, but, yes, that!